# Системный вызов open выгружает файл в оперативную память?

Tags: c, unix

Выгружает ли системный вызов open файл в оперативную память? Если да, возможно ли в linux узнать размер файла, не выгружая его в оперативную память?

Comment: Нет, не "выгружает". Иначе никакой оперативки не хватило бы.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Comment: Почитайте о файловых дискрипторах

Comment: `stat`, например - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html